# Command to check if svn remote revision is updated

Tags: batch-file, svn

I am very new to batch file.I am trying to write a batch file that will check in intervals if the svn remote's revision is updated. And if it finds the remote revision is newer, it will update the working copy. I have already tried `svn diff` and `svn status`. If somebody could help me with this problem I would be very grateful

Comment: what have you already tried? you should show some tries and ask for clarification, not to have your job done.

Comment: My work so far: `set SVNURL="svn://10.178.5.126/main/programs/modeller/trunk"
set CheckoutLocation="D:\SVN"
svn cleanup %CheckoutLocation%
svn diff %CheckoutLocation% %SVNURL% > updates.txt
for /f %%i in ("updates.txt") do set size=%%~zi
if %size% gtr 0 (call auto_build.bat 
) else (
del "D:\updates.txt"
)`

Comment: What about using simply `svn update` command ?

Answer (score 0):

I would back the comment by @LaurentH -- just run `svn update` and don't overcomplicate things unless you have a special case which you did not describe.

Anyway, if you are sure that you have a reason to check the repository before updating the working copy, try this approach:

1. [Create a working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.initial.html).
2. Run the [`svn status --show-updates`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) command (optionally with the [`--xml`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml) option).
3. Parse the output of the command to determine whether the working copy is up to date.

When you run the `svn status` with the [`--show-updates`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.show_updates) option, it places an asterisk next to items that are out of date in your working copy.

Note that there is a chance that you could make use of TortoiseSVN [Project Monitor](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-projectmonitor.html) or [Commit Monitor](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html) that periodically polls the repositories and checks for the updates.